# Tilted head Detection is failed in image but success in live stream

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, haar-classifier

I am working on a project where I need to detect face from the image and store it to directory for further use.
I am using openCV (Haar_cascade_classifier)
It is detecting only straight head. for detection of the tilted head.I tried tune version haar_cascade.but the problem it is only detecting face in live video.If I run webcamera and detect using haar_cascade_classifier_atl2.xml file . it detect the tilted head but if If I run loop from my image directory and pass images to detect face it is not detecting the same angle.means It is detecting in video but not from image (same angle)
here is the code

```
import cv2
from math import sin, cos, radians
import time
import fnmatch
import os

total_number_of_frame = 0
framedirectory = "D:/finalpaper/extractedframes"
number_of_extracted_frames = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('D:/finalpaper/extractedframes'), '*.png'))
print(number_of_extracted_frames)
face = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")

settings = {
    'scaleFactor': 1.3,
    'minNeighbors': 3,
    'minSize': (50, 50)
}

def rotate_image(image, angle):
    if angle == 0: return image
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((width/2, height/2), angle, 0.9)
    result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, (width, height), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return result

def rotate_point(pos, img, angle):
    if angle == 0: return pos
    x = pos[0] - img.shape[1]*0.4
    y = pos[1] - img.shape[0]*0.4
    newx = x*cos(radians(angle)) + y*sin(radians(angle)) + img.shape[1]*0.4
    newy = -x*sin(radians(angle)) + y*cos(radians(angle)) + img.shape[0]*0.4
    return int(newx), int(newy), pos[2], pos[3]

for i in range(number_of_extracted_frames):
    framenumber = str(i)+".png"
    #joining path to directory
    filepath = os.path.join(framedirectory,framenumber)
    frame = cv2.imread(filepath)
    for angle in [0, -25, 25]:
        rimg = rotate_image(frame, angle)
        detected = face.detectMultiScale(rimg, **settings)
        if len(detected):
            detected = [rotate_point(detected[-1], frame, -angle)]
        break

     # Make a copy as we don't want to draw on the original image:
    for x, y, w, h in detected[-1:]:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)


    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    cv2.waitKey(700)
```

If above code I use to run with web camera it detect face but if I am using my loop it is not detecting tilted head.

Comment: Are you trying to detect the angle? The face? or the head?

Comment: YScharf in result I need to detect the face. but problem is if face is not on 90degree angle. means it is tilted to any other angle. Detection is not successful.
I have number of images. I am running a loop in image directory but in some images faces are tilted so detection is unsuccesful

Comment: "If above code I use to run with web camera it detect face but if I am using my loop it is detecting tilted head." Is it supposed to be  "if I am using my loop it is !not! detecting tilted head."?

Comment: yes you are right. Just edited